# ¿Es "palabra altisonante" tomado como sinónimo de 'mal gusto' en algún lugar?

Tags: vulgaridades

Normalmente entiendo **palabras altisonantes** como su significado irónico, es decir, significando **groserías**. Pues [altisonante](http://dle.rae.es/altisonante) significa precisamente lo contrario

> *Altisonante.*
>   Se dice, por lo común, del lenguaje o estilo en que se emplean con frecuencia o afectadamente voces de las más llenas y sonoras.

¿Soy el único al que le parece que el significado real de esta palabra ha sido rebasado por su significado sarcástico?

Ejemplo 1. Aquí es claro el carácter irónico del adjetivo.

> A: El puto perro ya se orinó en la cocina.
>   B: ¡Vaya, qué altisonante! (Criticando a *A*)

Ejemplo 2. Pero aquí no

> El uso de palabras altisonantes por parte de *X*-gente es común.

Comment: Aunque esta es  una buena pregunta, quizá deberías cambiar la parte de "¿Soy el único al que le parece que..." para que no pueda tacharse a la pregunta de _"opinion based"_. Yo sugiero cambiarlo por algo como "¿Cuál es el significado de _altisonante_?" o "¿Qué otras acepciones/connotaciones tiene la palabra _altisonante_?". Incluso así es posible que esta pregunta no tenga una respuesta única, debido a diferencias regionales, pero por lo menos no estarán basadas en preferencias u opiniones personales.

Answer (score 3):

Es difícil encontrar una definición aceptada para [`altisonante`](http://buscon.rae.es/drae/srv/search?val=altisonantes) aparte de la que has incluido en la pregunta, pero por mi experiencia "lenguaje altisonante" o "palabras altisonantes" puede designar también:

1. Lenguaje vulgar o grosero.
2. Lenguaje pomposo o rimbombante (uso de palabras menos frecuentes o más sofisticadas o rebuscadas para sonar más culto, pero que tiene el efecto contrario de sonar pedante).

Aunque yo (español de España) lo relaciono mucho más con el segundo que con el primero (lenguaje altisonante es para mi grandilocuente y pomposo, más que vulgar o barriobajero) es posible que otros dialectos del español favorezcan la acepción de "vulgar o grosero" sobre las otras.

Comment: En Chile siempre lo entendí como vulgar o grosero.

Answer (score 0):

Altisonante se refiere al uso de groserías, palabrotas, maldiciones e improperios que algunas personas utilizan para expresarse. Palabras altisonantes se usa para referir la ésa forma de hablar. Ejemplo: "Juan le reclamó a Pedro con palabras altisonantes " ,léase con groserías.
En una respuesta leí que éran palabras pomposas ó rimbombantes a lo cuál se le llama hablar con grandilocuencia (el uso rebuscado de palabras poco comunes para aparentar ser una persona culta ó ilustrada).